# Check for integrability of а function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Is the function $f(x,y)=\dfrac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$ integrable on $\mathbb{R^2}$ ?

What is the general approach for investigating integrability?

Comment: You're asking about Lebesgue-integrability?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention it.

Comment: Express $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \lvert f(x,y)\rvert\,dx\,dy$$ in polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not integrable. Letting $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r$, your function is $\frac{\sin(r^2)}{r^2}$, whose integral over $\mathbb R^2$ is given in polor coordinates by
$$
2\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(r^2)}{r^2}r\,dr=2\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(r^2)}{r}\,dr
$$
So your function is integrable iff $\int_0^\infty \frac{|sin(r^2)|}{r}\,dr<\infty$. You can show the latter is infinite using the bound
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{|sin(r^2)|}{r}\,dr
\ge\sum_{k\ge 0}\int_{k\pi+\pi/4}^{(k+1)\pi-\pi/4}\frac{|sin(r^2)|}{r}
\ge\sum_{k\ge 0}\int_{k\pi+\pi/4}^{(k+1)\pi-\pi/4}\frac{1/2}{r}
$$
In words, use the lower bound $\frac{|sin(r^2)|}{r}\ge \frac1{2r}1_{E}$, where $E$ is the set where $\sin(r^2)>\frac12$.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$, you may show that the function is continuous inside the unit disk and bounded by $\dfrac1{x^2+y^2}$ outside of the unit disk.